Relationship between reconciliation sub-layer and PLS_Service Primitives, MII Signals in IEEE Clause 22
While reading the IEEE Standard for Ethernet, I'm confused about the direction of the arrows in this figure:

(The arrows point from RS sub-layer to PLS_Service Primitives.)
First, I want to know if the following points are correct:

The relationship between PLS_Service Primitives and MII Signals: The PLS_Service Primitives are logical representation, and MII Signals are the real physical signal lines.
The left part(PLS_Service Primitives) and the right part(MII Signals) are the same thing: the PLS sub-layer. Or more accurately to say is that they connect to PLS sub-layer.
PLS_xx.request: the primitives sent from MAC sub-layer to PLS sub-layer.
PLS_xx.indication: the primitives sent from PLS sub-layer to MAC sub-layer.

Then, if all above are correct, why do the the arrows surrounded by the red box in above picture point from RS sub-layer to the PLS_xx.indication in PLS_Service Primitives, while the corresponding arrows in MII Signals are point to RS sub-layer. In my mind, the RS sub-layer is the proxy of MAC sub-layer. Why does MAC sub-layer send PLS_xx.indication?

PLS is intended for use with AUI between PLS and PMA, see clauses 6 and 7. It's the 10 Mbit/s precursor of the later and more stringent PCS sublayer.
The diagram you show is for 10/100 Mbit/s interfaces, so it works with both MII (100M) and PLS (10M). The Reconciliation sublayer maps signals between MII and PLS, like a translator.
Note that MII and AUI or optional interfaces between sublayers. It's quite possible and likely even common to omit backward compatibility and run 10M over (modified) MII which then doesn't require neither PLS signaling nor reconciliation.

"so it works with both MII and PLS", does it mean that MII and PLS are something in same level? But learning from the spec, I thing they are not the same thing, It seems that MII is the interface between PLS and MAC, and RS is is the proxy of MAC. Or another question: can MAC directly communicate to PLS without MII?

AUI/PLS is for 10M, MII/PCS is for 100M. Keep in mind that AUI and MII are optional interfaces to enable interoperation between generic MAC and PHY implementations. It's quite possible (and likely common) to omit AUI compatibility and run 10M over MII.

From figure 22-1 in clause 22, for 10Mb/s, the layer or interfaces from bottom to MAC are: MEDIUM --(MDI)-- PMA --(AUI)-- PLS --(MII)--RECONCILIATION; While those for 100Mb/s or 1Gb/s are: MEDIUM --(MDI)-- PMD -- PMA -- PCS -- MII/GMII -- RECONCILIATION. It seems that RS and MII are over PLS or PCS, while AUI are between PLS and PMA, which is not like that "AUI/PLS is for 10M, MII/PCS is for 100M." AUI and MII are not the same level thing.
But, from figure 6-1 in clause 6, it seems that PLS can also directly connect to MAC. So you are right, MII is optional.

To understand the  meaning of the arrow in the diagram in original question, I'd like to ask: how MAC and PLS connect directly? I didn't see any implementation, the spec only discusses PLS_Service, but that seems to be just abstract methods.

That's what the Reconciliation sublayer is for: to present a uniform MII interface to the MAC - see figure 22-1. Without it, the MAC would have to talk to the PLS directly, but that interface is only defined logically, not physically - see clause 6.
